# How to use the "using" keyword to define a function prototype/signature

Tags: c++, alias, typedef, using

In my efforts to port my C++ code to better (and more consistent) use of "Modern C++," my latest round of changes involves replacing `typedef int32_t I2Arr[2]` aliasing to the more modern `using I2Arr = int32_t[2]` style. This works fine for 'simple' (scalar) types, and is **especially useful** for defining function pointers:

```
using IFunc = int32_t(*)(int32_t, int32_t);
```

looks so much clearer (IMHO) than:

```
typedef int32_t(IFunc*)(int32_t, int32_t);
```

However, I've just become a bit stuck with replacing a `typedef` for an actual function prototype (not a pointer-to-function). For example, I have the following code, using the 'old-style':

```
typedef int32_t MaskMaker(int32_t, const uint8_t *, uint8_t *);
static MaskMaker *maskMakers[maskNum];
```

Now, maybe (probably) I'm being really dim here, but I just can't figure out a way to convert this to the `using` style of aliasing. Can anyone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
using MaskMaker = int32_t(int32_t, const uint8_t *, uint8_t *);
```

That's it, really.

Comment: Which is what I tried, but never got round to compiling it because Visual Studio's wonderful IntelliSense immediately came up with "function definition for int32_t not found!"

Answer (score 4):

It is the same approach as with the typedef declaration.

```
using MaskMaker  = int32_t( int32_t, int32_t );
static MaskMaker *maskMakers[maskNum];
```

So if you have a declaration like this

```
typedef int32_t MaskMaker(int32_t, const uint8_t *, uint8_t *);
```

then just move the name `MaskMaker` in the left side of an alias declaration and remove the decl-specifier typedef..

```
typedef int32_t MaskMaker(int32_t, const uint8_t *, uint8_t *);
using MaskMaker = int32_t (int32_t, const uint8_t *, uint8_t *);
```

By the way pay attention to that the typedef declaration can look also like

```
int32_t typedef MaskMaker(int32_t, const uint8_t *, uint8_t *);
```

that is it can be placed in any order relative to other decl-specifiers.:)

And because alias-declaration and typedef declaration are both declarations they can be present together. For example

```
int32_t typedef MaskMaker(int32_t, const uint8_t *, uint8_t *);
using MaskMaker = int32_t (int32_t, const uint8_t *, uint8_t *);
static MaskMaker *maskMakers[maskNum];
```

Comment: Thanks, Vlad! Like I said in the other answer, it's what I actually tried but was 'advised' against it by IntelliNonSense.