# Why does `using X = int32_t()` cause a VS warning that it can't find the function definition for 'int32_t'?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

The template parameter for `std::function` is in the form `T(...)`. I want to use `using` to label some of those template parameters like the following:

```cpp
using const_s32_sig = int32_t();
using const_s32 = std::function<const_s32_sig>;

using identity_sig = int32_t(int32_t);
using identity = std::function<identity_sig>;
```

For some reason, VS gives me the following warning:

[image]

only for the first *sig* definition. However, this only happens when the type name is typedef'd (e.g. `int32_t`, ...), and that's not the case for non-typedef'd data types such as regular `int`s.

I reckon it is harmless (I am perceiving the expected behavior) but I want to know if this can affect me in any way and how to resolve it, if possible?

Comment: @drescherjm I probably did not state it quite well. I don't know the name of such type names: `return_type(parameter_type1, parameter_type2, ...)`. But that's what I want to achieve by using `using`.

Comment: Did you forget to include <cstdint> ?

Comment: @user17732522 Ops, sorry. It's my bad. I took the screenshot immediately after changing from `uint32_t` to `int32_t` so probably IntelliSense (or whatever its name) did not have enough to react :D. I will change it to the correct screenshot.

Comment: @ÖöTiib I have it included. This does not cause compile errors or anything, it's just a warning.

Comment: Then it is perhaps just usual IntelliDense.

Comment: I had a very similar issue when I first started using `using` instead of `typedef` for functions. It's just [IntelliSense being dumb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58393972/how-to-use-the-using-keyword-to-define-a-function-prototype-signature#comment103133636_58393998) and your code will compile without warning.

Comment: I use both `using x = int32_t();` and `using y = int32_t;`, no error occurs, the warning may be a false positive.

Comment: Probably a conflict, You could remove the functions that are not used by protecting them under macros.  #ifdef...#endif